# Magento 1.9 MIME ENABLE

Tags: magento-1.9, database

My Website is not show product slider missing due to MIME enable please help me how to fix this issue please check attachment screenshot images 
www.hafeezpk.com

[image: www.hafeezpk.com]

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are trying to load a php file as css.
try adding `header('Content-Type: text/css');` to the top of that file that you are trying to load so it can be treated as css.

Comment: pauldrodriguez@ after adding this in header ('Content-Type: text/css'); still not show slider images same issue MIME enable error please check new screenshot attachment links below after adding . https://ibb.co/Qf3j7bf
https://ibb.co/LZyxXNm

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that this is php code, so it needs to be inside php tags, like this:
```<?php header('Content-Type': text/css'); ?>```

Comment: pauldrodriguez@   i am adding this code <?php header('Content-Type': text/css'); ?>   in head.phtml file please check this link below please check and reply me because still show same error if wrong please reply me which file apply this code OR where is file location reply 
public_html/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/head.phtml                   https://ibb.co/ch0kFcz
https://ibb.co/jzZCz7C                                                             https://ibb.co/6RScYqp

Comment: why are you putting it in the head.phtml file?
the code should go in the file that contains the css style rules so that when it gets fetched it can be interpreted as a stylesheet. looking at the error, this is the file you should place it:
https://www.hafeezpk.com/skin//frontend/default/jm_sporty/wavethemes/jmbasetheme/profiles/default/default.css.php

can find this file and make sure the code above is at the top of that file. make sure there is no whitespace before the start of ```<?php```.

Comment: pauldrodriguez@ i am apply your given code for this place (hafeezpk.com/skin//frontend/default/jm_sporty/wavethemes/jmbasetheme/profiles/default/default.css.php) but still same error show please please check below links and reply me .                                               
 https://ibb.co/dQMX4Sq                                                     https://ibb.co/3zgzGkt

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, it should be ```<?php header('Content-Type: text/css') ?>```

note that i removed the second single quote in the middle.

Comment: pauldrodriguez@ i am add new code <?php header('Content-Type: text/css') ?> but still show same error please check this links below after update please check and reply me .                                                                           https://ibb.co/q5jNxgq
https://ibb.co/hHtTXDL

Comment: pauldrodriguez@ please answer my query i am waiting for your reply.